# How do i refer to a variable that was made in another view controller in swift

Tags: variables, swift, viewcontroller

How do i add the text to from my textfield into an array that is made in another `ViewController`.

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {
  var thingsToDo = []

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var enterTask: UITextField!

  @IBAction func addtask(sender: AnyObject) {
    thingsToDo += enterTask.text
  }
```

Comment: Can you please edit your post so it's readable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the prepareForSegue-method to pass objects to another viewcontroller. First you have to add global variable in your `SecondViewController`.

```
var theThingsToDo:[AnyObject]!
```

Then, in your `FirstViewController`, you can use the `prepareForSegue`-method and pass the value from your FirstViewController to your SecondViewController. It is important that you set the name of the segue in your Storyboard.

You can find the segue-identifier in the top right corner of Xcode:
[image]

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){
   if segue.identifier == "yourSegueIdentifier" {
     // Value of the FirstViewControllers variable 'thingsToDo' will be sent to the SecondViewController
     (segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController).theThingsToDo = thingsToDo          
   }
}

@IBAction func addtask(sender: AnyObject) {
    theThingsToDo += enterTask.text
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by name the segue in your story board how do you do that

Comment: You can click on the segue in the storyboard. Then in the inspector(top right corner of XCode) you can set an identifier.

Comment: im clickign on the segue but i cant find the indentifier box anywhere in the inspecter

Comment: I've added a picture into my post where it should be.

Comment: i think i might be selecting the wrong thing on the story board what exactly is the segua sorry im new to coding

Comment: No problem. The segue is the line between the two ViewControllers. It's like a connector. Like that.(It's an older picture, but I think it shows it well: http://www.appcoda.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Storyboard-Segue-Identifier.jpg

Comment: Yeah i thought so, thats what i ahve been clickign on but still nothing shows up in the inspecter. i think its becoause i am doing a tabbed application so i dint make the seques myself maybe i dont know

Comment: Yeah so what i did was add a new segue to the first view controller which was 'show' but it still says use of undelcared typed browser view controller

Comment: You have to replace the 'BrowserViewcontroller' with your 'SecondViewController'. That was just an example. But I will change it.

Comment: ok cool one slight little problem left in my secondviewcontroller when i try to add enter text into theThingsToDo it says anyObject is not identical to a uint8

Comment: You have to make sure that the variables have the same type. So replace AnyObject with Int.

Comment: i did and it keep saying int! is not identical to uint8